# Subtract property of an array of object from a preceding object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object as such

```
 "stock": [
    {
        "Quantity": -36,
        "Price": 74.55,
        "Consideration": 2683.8,
        "Direction": "SELL"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": -50,
        "Price": 74.14,
        "Consideration": 3707,
        "Direction": "SELL"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": 12,
        "Price": 77.15,
        "Consideration": -925.8,
        "Direction": "BUY"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": 15,
        "Price": 76.4,
        "Consideration": -1146,
        "Direction": "BUY"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": 19,
        "Price": 75.8,
        "Consideration": -1440.2,
        "Direction": "BUY"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": 20,
        "Price": 82.44,
        "Consideration": -1648.8,
        "Direction": "BUY"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": 10,
        "Price": 82.08,
        "Consideration": -820.8,
        "Direction": "BUY"
    },
    {
        "Quantity": 10,
        "Price": 82.49,
        "Consideration": -824.9,
        "Direction": "BUY"
    }
]
```

I am trying to subtract the PRICE property of each object from that of the preceding object and append the result as profit to that preceding object...

So basically from the first object in the array i'll have;

```
74.55 - 74.14 and the result will be appended to the second object as
profit: "result:
```

the only thing i've been only to think of is this

```
            let stockData = stock.map((stock) => {
            return {
                Quantity: stock.Quantity,
                Price: stock.Price,
                Consideration: stock.Consideration,
                Direction: stock.Direction,
            };
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < stockData.length; i++) {
            let profit = stockData[i].Price - stockData[i - 1].Price;
        }

        res.status(200).json({
            stock: stockData,
        });
```

And on the **stockData[i - 1].Price** i'm getting "can not read property Price of undefined"

Comment: _"I am trying to"_ - I don't see you actually _trying_ anything so far. _Show us_ what you tried so far, and give a proper explanation of what the problem with it was.

Comment: I guess that's my english being wrong there, should have said "want to"

Comment: A mere "I want" is not really an appropriate way to ask here either. This is not a code-writing service, you should really show some initial attempts at least.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this:

```
const result = stock.map((a,b) => (a.profit = a.Price - stock[b+1]?.Price || 0, a));

// map over stock array and set profit property of first element to difference between this and the next element (stock[b+1])
```

See in action:

```js
const stock = [{
    "Quantity": -36,
    "Price": 74.55,
    "Consideration": 2683.8,
    "Direction": "SELL"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": -50,
    "Price": 74.14,
    "Consideration": 3707,
    "Direction": "SELL"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 12,
    "Price": 77.15,
    "Consideration": -925.8,
    "Direction": "BUY"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 15,
    "Price": 76.4,
    "Consideration": -1146,
    "Direction": "BUY"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 19,
    "Price": 75.8,
    "Consideration": -1440.2,
    "Direction": "BUY"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 20,
    "Price": 82.44,
    "Consideration": -1648.8,
    "Direction": "BUY"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 10,
    "Price": 82.08,
    "Consideration": -820.8,
    "Direction": "BUY"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 10,
    "Price": 82.49,
    "Consideration": -824.9,
    "Direction": "BUY"
  }
]
const result = stock.map((a,b) => (a.profit = a.Price - stock[b+1]?.Price || 0, a));
console.log(result)
```